# Measuring Load Capacitance and resistance of 4~20mA transmitter

Tags: impedance

In order to make a spec sheet on a loop powered 4~20mA product, we need to measure the Device Capacitance and Device Resistance. 
Is there any standard procedure for measuring such parameters?

Answer (score 1):

A loop powered device should appear as an extremely high impedance (a current sink) over the compliance range, so you can simply change the voltage and measure the **change** in current. It would be reasonable to use mid-scale (12.00mA) if you're looking for a typical measurement. So you could vary the voltage from (say) 10V to 30V and calculate the resistance from Req = \$ \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}\$. If the current changes by 1\$\mu\$A (say from 12.000mA to 12.001mA) for a +20V change, the equivalent resistance is 20M\$\Omega\$. Usually you might pick voltages that are not quite at the extremes of the guaranteed compliance range in order to get a good-looking number for the datasheet (and to more accurately represent typical operating conditions). For example, if the device will work from 8V to 60V you might use 10V and 48V.

The output resistance is gain-dependent (on the internal circuitry) so it will likely vary quite a bit from unit-to-unit, as well as over temperature (it's not unusual to see a 5:1 or 10:1 ratio between typical precision op-amp gain at 25°C and worst-case gain over temperature and unit-to-unit variations) so be careful about quoting a guaranteed spec based on a single measurement at room temperature.

Capacitance of a loop powered device will tend to be the shunt capacitance in the schematic at high frequencies (usually there's a 10n or something like that effectively across the loop terminals).

Answer (score 0):

Resistance is simple enough, supply a DC current (or voltage) wait long enough and measure the voltage (or current).

Capacitance is essentially the same, injecting a signal and looking at the response.  First let me set the stage:  Often loads are more complex than ideal capacitors.  As such the capacitance you would like to know should have a frequency associated with it.  Essentially you're looking for the "re-actance" across a specific frequency range.  Which also relates to the "long enough" I mentioned in the first paragraph.  A capacitor at high enough frequency can easily act as an inductor, this is what makes ceramic and film type capacitors better for higher frequency than electrolytes like tantalum capacitors.

To answer the question regarding measuring capacitance, the simplest way is to inject a frequency (even square wave can suffice) in the middle of your range and measure the response.  Knowing the DC and the AC response you can calculate C and R.

Comment: How can I "Inject" a frequency? Do I inject by AC coupling with a coupling capacitor? or do I superimpose "noise"voltage on top of the supply voltage. If I do so, how can I measure the change in other parameter to calculate capacitance?

Comment: You would Inject it the same way you would inject DC.  Either a current drive or voltage drive source, and measure the voltage or current respectively.  Let me try to include that in my answer...

Comment: Actually... my answer is not really specific to a "loop powered device" and I might be offering a less than ideal answer.